# Select options with new lines issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I have the following rails code (it uses simple form):

`<%= f.input :color, collection: custom_colors.split(/\n/).reject(&:empty?) %>`

`custom_colors` comes from a text area where users are asked to enter entries seperated by new lines.

**The issue:** This displays correctly, however, when a user goes to edit, the color is not saved and the select is empty. I'm using a typical rails scaffold.

**The issue (continued)**: The reason I believe this is not working, is that when saved, the color looks like `blue\r\n`. However, when I do:

`<%= field.options.split(/\n/).reject(&:empty?) %>` it returns `blue\r`, which means the input won't match, as `blue\r\n` clearly does not equal `blue\r`

How do I fix this?

Comment: post rails stack trace

Comment: @Nithin, to be clear, this isn't producing an error, it simply isn't selecting the correct dropdown option when a user goes to edit. I could post the results of `Thread.current.backtrace` but it looks normal.

Comment: You mean to say, the save is happening properly?

Comment: @Nithin, yes the save is happening properly. Actually, now you say that, I think I have found the issue, however, I'm not sure how to solve it. When it's saved, the colors are saved like: `blue\\r\\n`, leading it to not match the array in simple form. How would I get it to save without the returns?

Comment: @Nithin, sorry it's actually saving `blue\r\n` not what i posted before. But same issue I believe.

Comment: I guess the fix should come from collection object, I guess that's what is appending additional chars and stored into db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your form.

```
<%= f.input :color, collection: custom_colors.split(/\n/).map(&:strip).reject(&:empty?) %>
```